# я столкнулся с таким вопросом Что делать՞

Tags: javascript

```
    var PwEL = document.getElementById("pw");
var copyEl = document.getElementById("copy");
var lenEl = document.getElementById("len");
var upperEl = document.getElementById("upper");
var lowerEl = document.getElementById("lower");
var symbolEl = document.getElementById("symbol");
var generateEl = document.getElementById("generate");
var numberEl = document.getElementById("number");
var upperLatters = document.getElementById("ABSDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
var lowerLatters = document.getElementById("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
var numbers = document.getElementById("0123456789");
var symbol = document.getElementById("~!@#$%^&*()_+=|");

function getLowercase() {
    return lowerLatters[Math.floor(Math.random() * lowerLatters.langth)];
}

function getUppercase() {
    return upperLatters[Math.floor(Math.random() * upperLatters.langth)];
}

function getNumber() {
    return numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
}

function getSymbol() {
    return symbol[Math.floor(Math.random() * symbol.length)];
}

function generatePassword() {
    var len = lenEl.value;
    let password = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var x = generateX();
        password += x;
    }
    PwEL.innerText = password;

}


function generateX() {
    var xs = [];
    if (upperEl.checked) {
        xs.push(getUppercase());
    }

    if (lowerEl.checked) {
        xs.push(getLowercase());
    }

    if (numberEl.checked) {
        xs.push(getNumber());
    }

    if (symbolEl.checked) {
        xs.push(getSymbol());
    }

    if (xs.length === 0) return "";
    return xs[Math.floor(Math.random() * xs.length)];
}



generateEl.addEventListener("click", generatePassword);
copyEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
    var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
    var password = PwEL.innerText;
    if (!password) {
        return;
    }

    textarea.value = password;
    document.body.appendChild(textarea);
    textarea.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    textarea.remove();
    alert('password copied to clipboard');

});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это не вопрос....

Comment: Ну вроде прямо на вашем скриншоте написано что делать

Comment: "use 'esversion: 6')."

Comment: я не знаю, что это такое

Comment: а что это за ошибка и когда она появляется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам просто надо переписать это:

```
"click", () => {
```

на это:

```
"click", function () {
```